# JSON comes in undefined, where is the data lost?

Tags: node.js, json, rest, post, postman

I am using postman to test a rest API I'm building for a project. I'm trying to send some data to a post method, but the data is getting lost somewhere between Postman and the endpoint.

I've tried tracing the data with console logs, but nothing comes out (req.body is undefined). I'm pretty sure the issue isn't with the endpoint or router, as the same error comes up in postman as in the console of my IDE, which means there's some sort of communication.

```
// json I'm putting into postman. validated with Jsonlint.com
{
    "Name": "testN",
    "file": "file1",
    "Path": "/home/userf",
    "userName": "user1"
}

// profileWrite.js
 const dbProfileWrite = require('../...db-ProfileWrite');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var app = express();
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

// my post method 
async function post(req, res, next) {
    try {
        console.log("attempting to parse data: " + req.body);
        let profile = req.body;
        console.log("data parsed, writing profiles");
        profile= await dbProfileWrite.writeProfile(profile);
        res.status(201).json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
module.exports.post = post;
```

**UPDATE 7/15/19**:I have recreated a microversion of my project that is having this issue on stackblitz. there's some sort of package error that I'm working on, but here's the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mvk7dg). I've recreated the methodology I'm using in my project with the router and all and looked at the example in the express docs. hopefully this helps isolate the issue.The data still comes in undefined when I post to this api through postman, so helpfully this much smaller view of the whole project helps.

Comment: You never use the variable `config` for anything.

Comment: fixed it, it was supposed to be profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue myself with a little help from John Schmitz. The issue was that I was defining the router and the server before actually telling it how to handle json bodies/ objects, so the body came through as the default undefined. In my `index.js`, the following is what fixed the code:

```
        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        app.use(express.json());
        app.use('/api/v1', router);
```

the key to this is that the app is told to use json and `express.urlencoded` before the router is declared. these actions have to happen in this order, and all before `app.listen` is called. once the app is listening, all of its params are set and you can't change them. Tl;dr: node is VERY picky, and you HAVE to define these things in the right place. thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Express framework, by the look of the post function. You need to use a middlewear function to process request body using [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). Make sure you are using the correct parser in this case

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: yes I am using express. how should I incorporate that bodyParser into the function? should it replace JSON.parse?

Comment: I replaced JSON.parse with bodyParser.json , and it worked. thanks for the help

Comment: the solution in fact didn't solve the problem, it just got rid of the error msg. not sure what else I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need body-parser anymore it was put back in to the core of express in the form of express.json, simply use `app.use(express.json())`.

To access the body of your request use req.body, it should come with a object with the keys representing the json sent;

```
 var app = express();
 app.use(express.json());


async function post(req, res, next) {
    try {
        console.log("attempting to parse data: " + req.body);
        let profile = req.body; // no need to use any functions to parse it
        console.log("data parsed, writing profiles");
        profile= await dbProfileWrite.writeProfile(profile);
        res.status(201).json(profile);
        console.log("profilecreated");
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```

See the express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#req.body)

Comment: ok cool. so if I want to access the objects in profile, would I do something like `profile.Name`? if I try to print the whole profile even when using your methodology, it still comes out undefined. is there a `toString()` method for it?

Comment: It should not come undefined  if you are using the middleware correctly, how are you posting the data? are you using the correct content type header?

Comment: yeah I'm using postman, and I have it set to application/json header type.

Comment: Are you using any other middleware? Try to remove any other middleware so we can triangulate the problem...

Comment: I have no other dependencies in that file aside from express, my router sends the request straight to this method from the endpoint.

Comment: Can we see the whole file?

Comment: Also try to reproduce the `req.body` example in the express documentation, so we can make sure where the problem lies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196389/discussion-between-egrimes-and-john-schmitz).

Comment: the req.body example uses a different API structuring method that won't work with mine. I have a physical router file and all whereas it has the routes directly in the method headers. my methods other than the routing differences are identical. I'll play around with it a bit more but I am utterly flummoxed as to what is wrong. Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: I have done what you asked with regard to recreating the code from the express docs. let me know if I can do anything else to help fix this issue.